# Explaining the behavior of sprintf in MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab

I have recently been perplexed by some of the behavior of sprintf. It appears to be inconsistent in my view and I haven't been able to exactly determine the logic behind some of its behavior. Here is one case that baffles me

```
C = [1 + 2i, 3+ 4i, 5+6i, 7+8i, 9+10i];
>> sprintf('%+d%+di\n',real(C(1:2)),imag(C(1:2)))

ans =

+1+3i
+2+4i


>> sprintf('%+d%+di\n',real(C(1:3)),imag(C(1:3)))

ans =

+1+3i
+5+2i
+4+6i
```

I would've expected it to print my complex numbers as in C. Do I need to explicitly create a new vector of interleaved inputs? I feel this is problematic when different types are involved.

EDIT: What I feel the expected output should be

```
>> sprintf('%+d%+di\n',real(C(1:2)),imag(C(1:2)))

ans =

+1+2i
+3+4i


>> sprintf('%+d%+di\n',real(C(1:3)),imag(C(1:3)))

ans =

+1+2i
+3+4i
+5+6i
```

Comment: So what would the desired output be?

Comment: @LuisMendo edited question for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sprintf command you have provided behaves as `sprintf('%+d%+di\n', [1, 3], [2, 4])` since `real(C(1:2))` returns [1, 3] and `imag(C(1:2))` returns [2, 4] which behaves as you've observed.

What you want to do is: `sprintf('%+d%+di\n', [1, 3; 2, 4])`

It should be accomplished by either looping over elements of `C` or with the following `sprinf('%+d%+di\n', [real(C(1:2)); imag(C(1:2))])`.

Comment: This answers my question. For the situation when both strings and numbers are involved. I'll just go with explicitly writing a loop.